# How to lower the entry to align it with the other labels?

Tags: php, css, html5-canvas, label, laravel-8

How could I make the labels of a form align with their respective inputs? I would like the label and the input to be on the same line

I'm using medias query this view is for mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj2B8.png)

For de moment i have this:

```
<div class="row my-3 aa">

    <div class="col-md-3 my-1">  
        <label name="labelCheck" id="labelCheck" class="form-group labelD" for="defaultCheck1">Cargador de baterias opera normal (SI/NO)</label>
       
        <select class="form-control v" name="Carg_bat_op_nor" id="Carg_bat_op_nor">
            <option value="Si">Si</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="NA">NA</option>
        </select>
  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 my-1">  
        <label name="labelCheck2" id="labelCheck2" class="form-group labelD" for="defaultCheck1">Rectificador opera normal (SI/NO)</label>
    
        <select class="form-control v" name="rectificador_op_nor" id="rectificador_op_nor">
            <option value="Si">Si</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="NA">NA</option>
        </select>      
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 my-1">  
        <label name="labelCheck3" id="labelCheck3" class="form-group labelD" for="defaultCheck1">Inversor opera normal (SI/NO)</label>
        <select class="form-control v bajar" name="inversor_op_nor" id="inversor_op_nor">
            <option value="Si">Si</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="NA">NA</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 my-1 temperatura_inv">
        <label class="labelD" for="temperatura_inv">Temperatura</label>
        <input class="form-control my-2 tem" type="text" step="any" id="temperatura_inv" name="temperatura_inv" value="{{ old('temperatura_inv') }}" required>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will be glad you took the time in the end.

Comment: I understand that this might have been answered before but the answer provided for duplicate is for using grid with plain css.

Comment: as for OP, change `col-md-3 my-1` to `col-md-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between` removing margins for the `col` and also remove `my-2` in the input.

Comment: this will use bootstrap's class to add flex and justify content.